# Java code editing

Tags: java, edit

Help, I cannot get my program to run successfully. It gives me an error with two inputs for midterm mark and final mark. I cannot get it to run fully with the appropriate end pop up. I've tried to write a program that accepts marks from the user and displays the appropriate letter grade for unknown number of students. My code is as follows.

```
        import javax.swing.*;
    public class StudentGrades_Hann{
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            String input ;
            input= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter Name, \n ID Number,\n Homework Mark, \n Assignment Mark, \n Midterm Mark, \n and Final Mark \n All Entrys Must Be Separated By Commas");

            int com;
            com= input.indexOf(",");

            String name ;
            name = input.substring(0,com);

            int com2;
    com2= input.indexOf(",", com+1);

    String idnumber ;
    idnumber = input.substring(com+1, com2);

    int com3;
    com3= input.indexOf(",", com2+1);

    String homeworkmark ; 
    homeworkmark = input.substring(com2+1, com3);

    int com4;
    com4= input.indexOf(",", com3+1);

        String assignmentmark ; 
        assignmentmark = input.substring(com3+1, com4);

        int com5;
        com5= input.indexOf(",", com4+1);

        String midtermmark ; 
        midtermmark = input.substring(com4+1, com5);

        int com6;
        com6= input.indexOf(",", com5+1);

        String finalmark ; 
        finalmark = input.substring(com4+1);

        double as ;
        as = Double.parseDouble (assignmentmark.trim());

        double hw ;
        hw = Double.parseDouble (homeworkmark.trim());

        double mm ;
        mm = Double.parseDouble (midtermmark.trim());



        double fm ;
        fm = Double.parseDouble (finalmark.trim());

        String grade ; 

        double totalmark ; 
        totalmark= 0.1*hw+0.1*as+0.3*mm+0.5*fm ;

        double mnf ;
        mnf= 0.5*fm+0.3*mm ;

        if(totalmark < 50 || mnf < 50) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,name + idnumber + "Fail") ;
        }
        else if (totalmark < 85) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name + idnumber + "A") ;
        }

        else if (totalmark < 75) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,name + idnumber + "B") ;
        }

        else if (totalmark <65) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name + idnumber + "C");
        }

        else if (totalmark <=50) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,name + idnumber + "D") ;
        }

        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry") ;
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Where you getting error? In which line I mean.

Comment: I am not sure but `input.indexOf(",");` these lines could be source of problem. try to use `String[] in = input.split(",");` It will split your input by `,` and will create new array of Strings.

Comment: Its not specific. I assume its in converting the string to double. I am getting an exception error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "80, 90"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
 at StudentGrades_Hann.main(StudentGrades_Hann.java:55)

Comment: 80 was the input for the midterm mark, 90 was the input for the final mark

Comment: @user2166241 Thats may be because your trying to parse int with double. Change them to `parseInt()`

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the index of `,` for the next value.

For the second value, if the input is `name, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1`, it will try to parse 
`"1, 1"`.

Use `String.split(",")`, check if the number of elements in array is what you expect and then parse them, like this pseudo-code:

```
String[] strings = input.split(",");
if (string.length == 6) { //name and 5 values
    name = strings[0];
    id = strings[1];
    ...
} else {
       //provided values are incorrect
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting an exception error "Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "80, 90"

You are trying to parse"80,90" somewhere in your code which is not parsable double . So you are getting  NumberFormatException.

So instead of doing so much labour in finding indexOf and substring operation . Just try

```
String[] splitted = input.split(",");
```

You are doing somewhere mistake in splitting the given string.
I found the mistake.

```
String finalmark ; 
    finalmark = input.substring(com4+1);
```

should be

```
String finalmark ; 
    finalmark = input.substring(com5+1);
```